# Processing parameters before calling the base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

is it possible to process parameters before passing them into a base constructor?

As in:

```
A --> B
```

Where A is an abstract class and B is the child class.

A's constructor is like so:

```
Protected A (MyObject myObject)
```

B's constructor is like so:

```
Public B (string objectName)
```

I want it to be something like this

```
Public B (String objectName) : base (MyObject myObject)
{
myObject = new MyObject (objectName);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do something non-trivial (that doesn't fit naturally into a single expression that you can inline into the `base` call), then the only way to do that is in a `static` method, for example:

```
public B (string objectName) : base (SomethingComplex(objectName))
{
    //...
}
static MyObject SomethingComplex(string objectName)
{
    // this can now be arbitrarily complex
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objectName))
        throw new ArgumentException("objectName")
    // etc
    return new MyObject(objectName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only as a single expression:

```
public B(String objectName) : base(new MyObject(objectName)) {
}
```

Note that since this runs before the class is constructed, it cannot access instance members.

If you want to run more than a single expression (eg, parameter validation), you can call a static method.